# Target content to one or several users in Liferay, without using an Audience Targeting group

Tags: liferay, audience

In Liferay, is there any way to target content (eg: articles) to individual users or user IDs, rather than group them in an Audience, and then selecting the audience?

Much obliged!

Comment: A User Group with a User Group Site and Web Content Display?  Can you give more detail about what you're trying to do? There's probably more than one way to skin this cat :)